# Handling text in html: associating attributes to sentences

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a text made of multiple sentences. I want to display this text like a regular text while giving styling attributes and action handlers to sentences. Right now I tried to put them in different tags such as `div` and `p` but each time what I get is this:

[image: What I have now]

Instead of:

[image: What I want]

I guess this is not possible to get what I want using simple html since I don't only want rectangle, I want the divisions to wrap. Any idea on how I could do?

Comment: Have a look at css word-wrap, overflow-wrap and similar things. And use spans inside one container. Without any code, can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div and p elements are block-level elements.  Putting each sentence in a block-level element causes each sentence to start on a new line.

What you can do it put each sentence in an inline element such as a "span," then style the span elements.

Comment: You can declare your div or p elements as inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
display: inline;
```

On your elements and then also add:

```
float: left;
```

This will display them one right after the other and stack them below if they run out of room.